# How to make cli_warn() and cli_abort() not print in white color?

Tags: r, error-handling, warnings, rlang

I'm migrating from `rlang` to `cli` for error and warning handling (and it's awesome).

However, I couldn't find out how to tell `cli_warn()` and `cli_error()` to have the same blueish color as in base R (and even `rlang` for warnings).

IMHO users are used to these colors and having them in white is a bit confusing and far less eye-catching.

For instance:

```r
cli::cli_abort(c("foo", i="bar"))
stop("foo")

cli::cli_warn(c("foo", i="bar"))
rlang::warn(c("foo", i="bar"))
```

[image: code output]

**Is there a global way to keep using `cli_*` for formatting but get the colors right? Otherwise, is there a higher reason the devs chose to have different colors in `cli`?**

Even best if the error could keep being orange but the rest is not just plain white like a mere print.

References:

- https://cli.r-lib.org/reference/themes.html
- https://cli.r-lib.org/reference/ansi_palettes.html
- https://cli.r-lib.org/articles/palettes.html